# Cannot ignore files for search with VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have modified both UserSettings and WorkSpaceSettings like so:

```
{
    "search.exclude": {
        "**/node_modules": true,
        "**/bower_components": true,
        "**/public-coverage": true,
        "**/public/dist": true,
        "**/public/static": true,
        "**/public/lib": true
      }
}
```

when I search for "xyz" in the search bar, I am still getting hits from the `public/dist` directory and `public-coverage` directory, as you can see in the screenshot:

[image]

Does anyone know how to do this right?

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/31819

Answer (score 3):

[image: Make sure this is checked]

Make sure this is checked. This is a common mistake.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 "search.exclude": {
    "node_modules": true,
    "bower_components": true,
    ...
 }
```

Comment: yeah the defaults were `"**/node_modules": true`, so I just used the same format, let me try it